# node as lattice sites in networkx

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx

I have tree-like graphs that look like long trunks with branches, and each branch can have "leaves" on it. It looks basically like (edges no pictured):

```
    o
   oo
    oo     o
    o      o     o
oooooooooooooooooooooooooo
    o
    o
```

The length of the trunk can be arbitrary, and each vertical branch is of order ten nodes, with the leaves only one node maximum. Each node of the trunk has at most 4 edges. Since the  vertical "leaves" are guarantied never to overlap, I would like to be able to convert a graph so that each node is at a point of a lattice and obtain a dictionary of the form

```
dict = {n1: (x1, y2), n2: (x2, y2), ...}
```

with `ni` the node ID and `(xi, yi)` a couple of integer indicating the position on the lattice.  I have tried to implement it myself by obtaining  the trunk using the maximum distance between all nodes of the graph `G`:

```
nodeList = list(G.nodes)
dic = {}
for i, n1 in enumerate(nodeList):
        for n2 in nodeList[i+1:]:
            dic[(n1, n2)] = networkx.shortest_path(G,source=n1,target=n2)

    dicLength = {k: len(dic[k]) for k in dic}
    k = max(dicLength, key=dicLength.get)
    trunk = dic[k]
```

I can then set the trunk as the x coordinate of the lattice:

```
lattice = {k: (i, 0) for i, k in enumerate(trunk)}
```

I then tried to compute the vertical branches by checking if the a node in the trunk has more than two neighbours and iterate from node to node from there but I'm running into troubles when encoutering leaves. Moreover it does not scale well for large trunks.

Is there a simpler way to do that with networkx?

EDIT: a minimal example would be:

```
G = nx.path_graph(10)
G.add_edges_from([(3,11),(11,12),(12,13),(13,14),(13,15),(1,16)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of what output you expect by adding the vertical branches of your graph, perhaps a minimal example would help clarify. But, if I understood the setting correctly, I'd suggest you to obtain the *trunk* of the graph in the following way instead.

You could start by finding the [`nx.eccentricity`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.distance_measures.eccentricity.html) of the graph, that is, the maximum distance between a given node and all other nodes. Then, by finding its maximum value, or in other words, then diameter of the graph, we can limit the search of the `shortest_path` to only the pair of maximally distant nodes in the graph (in the case of a single trunk with no branches in either ends it won't be necessary, finding the shortest path between both `extrema_cand` will suffice):

```
ecc = nx.eccentricity(G)
diam = max(ecc.values())
extrema_cand = [node for node, length in ecc.items() if length==diam]
```

Now we can look for the shortest paths only on the above subset of nodes:

```
from itertools import combinations
trunk=[]
for nodes in combinations(extrema_cand, r=2):
    trunk.append(nx.shortest_path(G,*nodes))
trunk = max(trunk, key=len)
```

By filtering on the `max` in the last line we're ensuring to keep nodes from opposite sides of the graph. Though as mentioned, if there is a single trunk, `nx.shortest_path(G,*nodes)` on the only pair of nodes in `extrema_cand` should suffice.

Then for the branches,  perhaps an idea could be to iterate over the trunk nodes, and discover the *branches* and subsequent leaves through a breadth-first-search, ignoring paths Co tianing nodes from the trunk, or already traversed.

Comment: I used one of your previous edits to get the lattice sites of both trunk and branches. When there are some leaves they share the same site. As a node on a branch can only have one leaf maximum, I check for duplicate lattice sites, check how many neighbour the associated node has. If it has only one neighbour, it's a leaf and a shift its position by one, and the script finishes. It will not work is there are more than one leaf per branch node, but I checked that it never happens in my cases.

Comment: Glad it helped! I rolled back as I thought of more efficient ways of doing do but didn't have much time... and also because it didn't contemplate these cases. I'm glad you managed to adapt it to get it to work though @Bulkilol